# Appfabric cache

Tags: caching, appfabric

I am downloading content files(zip) from server to iPhone, directly by specifying the server path in the iPhone . Is there a way to cache the content in server to Appfabric and iPhone to read the content from Appfabric cache.Any help or pointer would really help me meet the project deliverables.

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm understanding the question correctly (and do feel free to correct me if not), it boils down to 'can I get items cached in AppFabric directly onto an iPhone'.

Right now, the only client libraries for AppFabric are for .NET applications (and I don't see much likelihood of Microsoft producing any in Objective-C either :-P ). Also bear in mind that Windows Server Appfabric is designed to sit behind the firewall, not to be directly accessible from the Internet (although I'm *reasonably* sure you could get round this with a VPN client). So on the surface, the answer is 'no, you can't'. But you could put a website or webservice in front of AppFabric that returns items from the cache, and call that from the iPhone - that's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy will have to create a web service/application that hosts those files for you in appfabric and get served to the iphone over TCP/IP. Most likely you'll need win servers for doing that. If what you have is Linux, take a look at [Memcahced](http://memcached.org/).